# The Monotonicity of The Weighted Mean of Order t

Tags: analysis

I am trying to solve an exercise from Zorich:

$Let x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$, where $x_i \geq 0$ and $\alpha_i > 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and $\sum_{i = 1} ^ n \alpha_i = 1$. For any number $t \not = 0$ we consider the mean of order $t$ of the numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ with weights $\alpha_i$:

$$M_t(x, \alpha) =(\sum_{i = 1}^ n \alpha_i x_i ^ t) ^ \frac{1}{t}.$$

I am stuck on part c) of the exercise, which asks me to show that $M_t(x, \alpha)$ is nondecreasing for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and that it is strictly increasing if $n > 1$ and $x_is$ are nonzero.

I am taking the derivative of the function with respect to $t$, which I believe is

$$(\sum_{i =1 } ^ n \alpha_i x_i ^ t) ^ \frac{1}{t} \cdot (- \frac{1}{t ^ 2} \ln(\sum_{i = 1} ^ n \alpha_i x_i ^ t) + \frac{t \sum_{i =1} ^ n \alpha_i \ln x_i x_i ^ t}{t \sum_{i = 1} ^ n \alpha_i x_i ^ t}).$$

I am stuck on showing that this derivative is nonnegative for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Can sombody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This section of Wikipedia may help for an overall proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_power_means_inequality.

Comment: That was really helpful! Thanks!